# Trigger a function with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/wr0xLj7x/

So I've set up a very simple application to test the `ng-click` function:

js:

```
var choreApp = angular.module('choreApp', []);

choreApp.controller('choreCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.logChore = function(chore){
        alert(chore + ' is finished!')
    }
})

choreApp.directive('kid', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            done: '&'
        },
        template: "<input type=text ng-model='chore'/>{{chore}}</br>"
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller='choreCtrl'>
    <kid done='logChore()'></kid> <div class='button' ng-click='done({chore:chore})'>Button</div>
</div>
```

However, when I click `.button`, nothing happens. Literally nothing happens, no errors in the console or anything. Could someone explain why?

Comment: first of all directive tag not replacing with template

Comment: add this, <div ng-controller='choreCtrl' ng-app="choreApp">, you should see the error =)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to bootstrap add ng-app

```
<div ng-controller='choreCtrl' ng-app="choreApp">
```

then set jsfiddle to "No wrap in <head>" at upper left, instead of onLoad.

then the 'done()' method that you expected to call, which wraps logChore() will not be called, try adding:

```
choreApp.controller('choreCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.logChore = function(chore){
        alert(chore + ' is finished!')
    }

    $scope.done = function() {
        alert('done');
    }

})
```

if you create a link function in your directive and call scope.done() then logChore() should be called.